# How do I catch a hangup while gathering input from a user in Twilio?

Tags: twilio, twilio-studio

I have a Twilio Studio flow that uses the "Gather Input from User" during an outbound call.

I have widgets following all possible outcomes, including "No Input".

However, I have discovered that if the user hangs up during this step, the flow ends.

I need to capture the fact that the user hung up, but I can't figure out how.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I was about to suggest that you use the status callback URL on your number, but that works for inbound calls. I'm working with the Studio team here at Twilio to see if there is a way to get the status of an outbound call from Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

For an outbound call from the Studio widget there is no way to capture status events as you would for a call normally. There are two workarounds though.

Firstly, if you are recording the call then you can set the recording status callback, which will notify you once the recording is ready and thus the call is over.

Alternatively, you will need to poll the [Studio REST API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/rest-api) to keep an eye on running executions and when they finish.